# Disable PVP in Minecraft with a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to disable PVP in Minecraft Java edition with a command, if I already have teams created that are needed?

**Things I've Considered/Tried**

- Creating a team named `all`, giving it to everyone and turning off `friendlyFire`. This does not work for me because I already have teams that I use.
- Changing the server properties. This does not work for me because I need to be able to change it from in-game. This is for a minigame I am making.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the weakness effect which when having a high strength does not allow the player to deal any damage. `/effect give @a weakness 9999 255 true` will give weakness 255 to all players until you clear it and also hide the bubbles to make sure they don't annoy anyone.

*Note for Bedrock Edition players*:

There is a gamerule command `/gamerule pvp false` which will disable PVP.

Comment: will that make it so the player can't do damage to mobs?

Comment: The first command will also stop damage to mobs, the second will not.